# Find out the distance between two specific words in a String

Tags: java

I want to write a Java program to determine how many words are between two given words in a String (the distance).

For example in the String "The picture quality is great of this camera."
The distance between "quality" and "great" is one.

Comment: System.out.println("1");

Comment: @Osiris haha, but not justified. Op gave an example to clarify the problem. You are being a bit pedantic in this case (-:

Comment: Closed because it's worded like a homework (which I assume it is) and it's begging for code rather than asking. It also shows no research effort.

Comment: Dang! Just after I answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a pointer, you can optimize the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "The picture quality is great of this camera";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    boolean start = false;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        String token = st.nextToken();
        if(token.equals("quality")){
            start = true;
            continue;
        }
        if(start) {
            if(token.equals("great")){
                start = false;
            }
            else {
                numberOfWords++;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(numberOfWords);
}
```

Comment: Downvote ! Sensible enough to leave a comment ?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I guess it's because you didn't show any parametrization and used an overly complex approach by tokenizing the whole String.

Comment: Then please upvote and restore some sanity.

Answer (score 2):

1. Maybe start with String.split(...) to get an array of all the words.
2. Then you can search the array for both words. One you know the index of both words you can determine the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "The picture quality is great of this camera";

        // happy flows
        System.out.println(findDistance(input, "quality", "great"));
        System.out.println(findDistance(input, "picture", "of"));

        // words in reversed order
        System.out.println(findDistance(input, "camera", "great"));

        // non occurring words
        try {
            System.out.println(findDistance(input, "picture", "camcorder"));
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Expected exception caught, message was: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static int findDistance(String input, String word1, String word2) {
        // check input
        if (input == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input cannot be null");
        }
        if (word1 == null || word2 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Two words should be provided");
        }

        // determine boundaries
        int pos1 = input.indexOf(word1);
        int pos2 = input.indexOf(word2);

        // check boundaries
        if (pos1 < 0 || pos2 < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both words should occur in the input");
        }

        // swap boundaries if necessary to allow words in reversed order
        if (pos1 > pos2) {
            int tmp = pos1;
            pos1 = pos2;
            pos2 = tmp;
        }

        // obtain the range between the boundaries, including the first word
        String range = input.substring(pos1, pos2);

        // split the range on whitespace
        // minus one to not count the first word
        return range.split("\\s").length - 1;
    }
```

Have a nice day (which great picture quality)!

Comment: Why do you use an array parameter when you expect exactly two words?

Comment: @Jacob You read my mind. Just changed that (-: